# DNS event ID 4000 on SBS 2011

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-sbs-2011

We're getting the following event ID 4000 (Source: DNS) on a Windows SBS 2011 SP1 server:

> The DNS server was unable to open Active Directory.  This DNS server is configured to obtain and use information from the directory for this zone and is unable to load the zone without it.  Check that the Active Directory is functioning properly and reload the zone. The event data is the error code.

This issue with DNS is preventing Exchange services from running.

I have tried restarting the server, removing/installing the DNS role, and adding/removing the network adapter.

When trying to open DNS Manager I get the following error:

[image: DNS Manager Access Denied]

[image: DNS Manager server inaccessible]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How are the DNS client settings on the server configured? What is the server using for DNS? It should be using itself.

Comment: The server is using itself for DNS. No secondary DNS address on the network adapter.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this issue by running the following command on our domain server:

```
nltest /sc_change_pwd:<fqdn>
```

Afterwards we had to restart the server.

Comment: While this answer may be factually correct it would be much more useful if you explained what this command does.

Comment: I asked this question in January 2014! Cannot recall now how the issue was resolved.